# How to use log4j2 with Android for logcat output?

Tags: java, android, maven, logging, log4j2

I want to use log4j2 to produce logcat output from an Android app.
Seems that the 6 standard log4j2 log levels (fatal, error, warn, info, debug, trace) are matching well to the 6 log levels of logcat (wtf, e, w, i, d, v). The log4j logger name (typically the class name) should be used for the logcat tag.

[This](https://github.com/Joe-Merten/Mpjoe/tree/b8564c852e0955c7b9342ad928957505edd4b88d/Android) small Android project compiles using `mvn clean install` (after installing Android sdk et cetera).

In it's main activity ([Mpjoe.java](https://github.com/Joe-Merten/Mpjoe/blob/b8564c852e0955c7b9342ad928957505edd4b88d/Android/src/main/java/de/jme/mpjoe/android/Mpjoe.java)), it includes something like:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
// ...

public class Mpjoe extends Activity {
    static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger();
    // ...
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        logger.fatal("=== Initialized ===");
    }
}
```

As mentioned [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/maven-artifacts.html), I'd added the required dependencies to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For configuring log4j2 without a configuration file, I use [this](https://github.com/Joe-Merten/Mpjoe/blob/b8564c852e0955c7b9342ad928957505edd4b88d/Common/src/main/java/de/jme/toolbox/logging/Log4jConfigure.java) helper class (which uses the same way as mentioned [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-952)).

It compiles without errors, but when running I got the message:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...
```

When checking the system property `java.class.path`, it returns `"."`, but this seems a normal circumstance (as described on http://developer.android.com).

Any suggestions how to solve that?